# Programmatically populate ribbon, with Button

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

Creating custom "Send on behalf of" button for shared mail box I would like to create the `RibbonGroup` and `RibbonButton` and add them to the `RibbonTab` programmatically.

My issue is that in `CreateButtons()`, adding button to `RibbonGroup` and `RibbonTab` will cause an error *"Collection is read-only"*. Even if those are use in the designer as well.

```
RibbonGroupReply.Items.Add(tempButton);
RibbonGroupNew.Items.Add(tempButton);
this.tab_MainComplement.Groups.Add(RibbonGroupNew);
```

I also try to use other method that were in the designer, I can now add in the `RibbonGroup` but not in the `RibbonTab`:

```
tab_MainComplement.SuspendLayout();
RibbonGroupReply.SuspendLayout();
this.SuspendLayout();
```

I see no way out as dropping the tab for a new one will raise the same error on 
`this.Tabs.Add(New_Tab);` and adding the `CreateButtons` method inside the designer `InitializeComponent` break the layout and do not give better result.

Code :

```
public partial class BtnSender
{
    internal List<ButtonInfo> Buttons;

    private void BtnSender_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadButtonsList();
        CreateButtons();
    }

    private void CreateButtons()
    {
        //CreateNew Group           
        var buttonsNew = Buttons.Where(x => (x.Type & ButtonType.New) == 0);
        if (buttonsNew.Any())
        {
            OutlookRibbon.RibbonGroup RibbonGroupNew = this.Factory.CreateRibbonGroup();

            RibbonGroupNew.Label = "Nouveau Message";
            RibbonGroupNew.Name = "Nouveau Message";

            foreach (var butt in buttonsNew)
            {
                var tempButton = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
                tempButton.ControlSize = RibbonControlSize.RibbonControlSizeLarge;
                tempButton.Image = global::CustomExpeditor.Properties.Resources.basic_mail;
                tempButton.Label = butt.Label;
                tempButton.Name = butt.Name + butt.Label.Replace(" ", string.Empty) + "New";
                tempButton.Description = butt.Address;
                tempButton.ShowImage = true;
                tempButton.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.Btn_SenderSI_Click);
                RibbonGroupNew.Items.Add(tempButton);
            }
            this.tab_MainComplement.Groups.Add(RibbonGroupNew);
        }

        //CreateReply Group
        var buttonsReply = Buttons.Where(x => (x.Type & ButtonType.Reply) == ButtonType.Reply);
        if (buttonsReply.Any())
        {
            OutlookRibbon.RibbonGroup RibbonGroupReply = this.Factory.CreateRibbonGroup();
            //tab_MainComplement.SuspendLayout();
            //RibbonGroupReply.SuspendLayout();
            //this.SuspendLayout();

            RibbonGroupReply.Label = "Répondre à";
            RibbonGroupReply.Name = "Répondre à";

            foreach (var butt in buttonsNew)
            {
                var tempButton = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
                tempButton.ControlSize = RibbonControlSize.RibbonControlSizeLarge;
                tempButton.Image = global::CustomExpeditor.Properties.Resources.basic_mail;
                tempButton.Label = butt.Label;
                tempButton.Name = butt.Name + butt.Label.Replace(" ", string.Empty) + "Reply";
                tempButton.Description = butt.Address;
                tempButton.ShowImage = true;
                tempButton.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(Btn_ResponseSI_Click);
                RibbonGroupReply.Items.Add(tempButton);
            }
            tab_MainComplement.Groups.Add(RibbonGroupReply);
        }
    }

    private void LoadButtonsList()
    {
        // Will evolve to a more configurable list in the future. 
        Buttons = new[] {
            new ButtonInfo{ Label="Mail Test", Address="MailTest@domain.not", Type=ButtonType.New & ButtonType.Reply },
            new ButtonInfo{ Label="Serv Info", Address="MailTest@domain.not", Type=ButtonType.New & ButtonType.Reply  },
            new ButtonInfo{ Label="Serv Log", Address="MailTest@domain.not", Type=ButtonType.New & ButtonType.Reply  },
            new ButtonInfo{ Label="Titi", Address="MailTest@domain.not", Type=ButtonType.New  }
        }.ToList();
    }
}

public class ButtonInfo
{
    public string Name, Label, Address;
    public ButtonType Type;
}
[Flags] public enum ButtonType { New = 1, Reply = 2 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those buttons are read-only right after initialization, just like the groups, tabs, etc. Adding them dynamically after initialization doesn't work.

I have solved this a few times by adding buttons up-front, and dynamically fill them with the correct labels. Some control types do allow dynamic buttons, like a ribbon gallery.

Comment: Well it looks like not only Buttons are read only but also, group, tab, and main container. I will try with ribbon asap.

Comment: Yes, all those are read-only. All those are generated into the `Ribbon.xml`.